# How to group by a pandas.Dataframe's columns based on the indexes and values of another pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I'm trying to group by a dataframe's columns together based on another pandas.Series' values and indexes. The Series' indexes refer to the DataFrame's columns but there could be more elements to it. What is the best pythonic way to do this?

For further clarity, here's the unit test I'm trying to resolve (using pytest):

```
    def test_sum_weights_by_classification_labels_default_arguments():
    portfolio_weights = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2],
                                      [0.25, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2],
                                      [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4]],
                                     index=['2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04'],
                                     columns=['ABC', 'DEF', 'UVW', 'XYZ'])

    security_classification = pd.Series(['Consumer', 'Energy', 'Consumer', 'Materials', 'Financials', 'Energy'],
                                        index=['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'RST', 'UVW', 'XYZ'],
                                        name='Classification')

    result_sector_weights = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
                                          [0.25, 0.5, 0.25],
                                          [0.2, 0.7, 0.1]],
                                         index=['2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04'],
                                         columns=['Consumer', 'Energy', 'Financials'])

    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(clb.sum_weights_by_classification_labels(portfolio_weights, security_classification),
                                  result_sector_weights)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope I'm respecting SO's guidelines here. I know there are more than one question, but it's really about making my code pythonic since I'm about to do a lot of similar functions, only want to get the best practices. Thanks

Comment: Best practices is a matter of opinion. SO is not a code review site. There is a sister site for that. SO is made to solve programming issues, which you do not appear to have. I am therefore voting to close.

Comment: Yes that's what I feared, sorry about that @Mad Physicist. I'll review the question or delete it, I think there is still value for someone who tries to group by based on another df or series. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Hope it is better now. Keeping this post because after searching, doesn't seem to have something similar elsewhere, hope it might help someone in the future. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I have found a solution. Here's what I came up with using `pandas.Series.map` on the DataFrame's columns:

```
def sum_weights_by_classification_labels(security_weights, security_classification):

    classification_weights = security_weights.copy()
    classification_weights.columns = classification_weights.columns.map(security_classification)
    classification_weights = classification_weights.groupby(classification_weights.columns, axis=1).sum()

    return classification_weights
```

Alternatively using `pandas.DataFrame.merge`:

```
def sum_weights_by_classification_labels(security_weights, security_classification):

    security_weights_transposed = security_weights.transpose()
    merged_data = security_weights_transposed.merge(security_classification, how='left', left_index=True, 
                                                    right_index=True)
    classification_weights = merged_data.groupby(security_classification.name).sum().transpose()

    return classification_weights
```

And for the second solution need to add this line to the unit test because cannot merge a Series without a name (the added column needs to have one):

`result_sector_weights.columns.name = security_classification.name`

I'm keeping this post hoping it might help someone in the future.

This is the way...

Comment: If you're using `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`, you might as well just use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).